# Mat-Button Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following markup:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
        <mat-form-field class="company-filter-form">
            <mat-select placeholder="Actionss">
                <mat-option [value]=""></mat-option>
                <mat-option value="Delete">Delete</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field class="company-filter-form">
            <button mat-flat-button color="primary">Apply</button>
        </mat-form-field>
```

I then get this rendering error:

```
ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.
    at getMatFormFieldMissingControlError (form-field.js:109)
```

All modules are imported MatButtonModule, MatFormFieldModule & MatInputModule.

How can i add a mat-button to the same row as a mat-select?

Comment: Buttons inside of the `mat-form-field` element are invalid - seeing that you're intending for the button to be a "submit" button, you could try including a `type` attribute set to `submit`.

Comment: MatFormFIeld is used for additionnal behavior on form tags and expects to wrap form tags. That's why you get this error on mat-form-field wrapping the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not wrap the buttons with `mat-form-field`. MatFormField is a component used to wrap several Angular Material components and apply common Text field styles such as the underline, floating label, and hint messages. Instead of `mat-form-field`, you can put just a `div`. It will resolve your problem.

```
    <div class="company-filter-form">
        <button mat-flat-button color="primary">Apply</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added a div and just need to style it to match (which is a bit of a pain)